# Loading String value using ParseConfig from Parse.com with new line character

Tags: string, parse-platform, uiwebview, nsstring, config

i have a problem to load a String value using ParseConfig from Parse.com with new line character.

The new line character is ignored, is that normal or i'm doing something wrong?

There is any other solution to get a text with new line character without using html code and uiwebview?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I'm posting here for posterity as I had the same issue.

On Parse, use another character such as `<br>` where you want a new line in your String.

Then, in Swift or Objective C, replace `<br>` with `\n`, which is recognized by Swift:

**Swift:**

```swift
// Assume you've loaded a String from Parse, called 'rawStringFromServer'
let newString = rawStringFromServer.replacingOccurrences(of: "<br>", with: "\n")
myUILabel.text = newString
```